# How do I change the properties of my subsubsection headers (ie. make them bold)?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I want to be able to put my subsubsections in bold - currently they are displayed in italics by default.

What I have:

**1. Section**

**1.1 Subsection**

*1.1.1 Subsubsection*

What I want:

**1. Section**

**1.1 Subsection**

**1.1.1 Subsubsection**

The top of my Latex document currently looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{revtex4}    
\usepackage{times}                              
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,
 top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}    
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}                       
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,epsfig,ulem}  
\usepackage{amsmath}                            
\usepackage{etoolbox}                      
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{(}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\frontmatter@RRAP@format}{)}{}{}{}
\renewcommand\Dated@name{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}

\pagestyle{fancy}                           
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{Insert Title Here}

\def\thetable{\arabic{table}}
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}  

\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}

\begin{document}                    
\end{documnet}
```

Comment: You have many options: `sectsty`, `titlesec`, etc.

Comment: You're presumably using the `revtex4` document class for a good reason, e.g., because you're planning to submit a paper to a journal which requires authors to employ the `revtex4` class. If that's the case, it's probably a poor idea to modify the appearance of subsubsection-level headers. For one, it'll immediately earn you the enmity of the journal's editorial staff, and the editors may decide to reject the paper solely based on its failure to conform to `revtex4` formatting conventions.

Comment: Off-topic: No need to load both `graphics` and `graphicx`. And, almost certainly no need to load `epsfig`.

Comment: @JouleV - The `sectsty` package is incompatible with the `revtex4` document class.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I did not notice the document class when commenting.

Comment: @Sveinung Although there are answers specific for Revtex, the answer in the linked question can still be used here, because it uses `titlesec`. That is the reason of closure.

Comment: @JouleV Using `titlesec`is not the best option, and the other answers do not answer the question.

Comment: @Sveinung I use the singular form of word "answer". That means I only pointed to one answer (sorry if I was not clear). And that answer _can_ be used. We can never say this answer or that answer is the best option. It is very opinion-based. I keep my opinion: I voted for closure.

Comment: @JouleV And I disagree.

Comment: @Sveinung Then you don't vote to close it. Nothing simpler :))

Answer (score 1):

*NB! Take note of @Mico’s comment to your question before you apply this patch*

In Revtex v4.2c, `\subsubsection` is define with the following command:

```
\def\subsubsection{%
      \@startsection
        {subsubsection}%
        {3}%
        {\z@}%
        {.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
        {.5cm}%
        {\normalfont\small\itshape}%
    }
```

I tried to redefine the command:

```
\def\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection
    {subsubsection}%
    {3}%
    {\z@}%
    {.8cm \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {.5cm}%
    {\normalfont\small\bfseries}%
}
```

This redefinition changes the *font* to boldface, but the *alignment* of the subsection was changed, too. Obviously, the alignment is applied later and is cancelled if you redefine the command by using `\def`.

`\patchcmd` worked better:

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{revtex4}    
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}                    
\section{test}
\subsection{Testing}
\subsubsection{More testing}
\end{document}
```

Just add the line:

```
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
```

after the other `patchcmd` lines in your example, and you have your bold subsubsection. .

Comment: Welcome (back)!